# Is there a term for words that have the same transliteration?

Tags: single-word-requests

*Context*: I'm working on Anki decks (think fancy flashcards). One of the goals is to be able to recognize/spell words by their transliterations, but some words have identical transliterations and I'd need to list them: if I show *basilēa* I want to accept either βασίλεια ('queen') or βασιλεία ('kingdom') because they're words-with-the-same-transliteration, though they have different pronunciation and spelling.  If I show *yú* I want to accept 魚, 於, etc.

I don't want to call them homographs because I would use that for words that are homographs in the original script, which can be but aren't always words-with-the-same-transliteration — Chinese 行 might be *háng* ('line, profession') or *xíng* ('walk, do, OK').

So,
*Question*: If I wanted to list a word's words-with-the-same-transliteration, what would be the best thing to call them?

Comment: A transliteration is usually a representation of the pronunciation of the word. So how can they have different transliterations if they have different pronunciations?

Comment: @Barmar Transliterations can vary widely from pronunciation (look up how Wylie transliteration handles Tibetan).  Basically it's just a way of converting the characters of one script to another, and transliteration methods are not always perfect or reversible (especially when the source language isn't phonetically written to begin with).

Comment: OK, I guess I'm just used to the transliterations that are used in Hebrew prayer books, which are intended to allow non-Hebrew readers to be able to say the prayers approximately as they would if they could read the language.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the fact that words/symbols in some *other* language might correspond to multiple *English* words is irrelevant to how English itself works from the point of view of native Anglophones (as addressed on ELU).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm looking for an English word similar to homophone, homograph, homonym, but that applies to words transliterated from one writing system to another.  If mentioning other languages makes it off-topic, then imagine examples concerning other written forms of English like shorthand or Braille.

Comment: @Muskworker: I'd have thought Braille and shorthand are peculiar to English (or at least, that you'd have to completely re-implement them for use with other languages), and that any given word in either representation would be equal to one and only one "standard English" word. The only *real* connection between your *queen, kingdom* examples is that another language might have a single symbol covering both. But this is unknown/irrelevant from the Anglophone's perspective, so why would he even recognise the existence of the category, let alone have a word for it?

Comment: @FumbleFingers For a concrete example, "⠋"  in Braille can transliterate to "F", "-self", "from", or "6".  The question is essentially what can I call those four expansions of the Braille symbol, which all share a common transliteration into Braille?

Comment: @FumbleFingers We can use English to talk about the process of translating between different languages. That's why English might have a word for this, even though the languages we're translating between don't necessarily include English.

Comment: Words with the same transliteration are *very likely* to be homophones, and I can use that term for systems where identical transliterations are identically pronounced, but I'd much prefer a term I could use across all cases.

Comment: (Maybe this question is better for lingustics.SE?)

Comment: It's all Greek to me.

Comment: Not really relevant to the question, but if you use _ē_ to transliterate _ει_, what do you use for _η_? (And presumably the same for _ου_ and _ω_?)

Comment: Also, how language-agnostic should these be? For example, should _kan_ match both Mandarin 坎/看/刊, Japanese 間/感/館, Greek _κάν_ (= _κατά_ before _ν_) and _κἄν_ (= _και εάν_), Armenian _կան_ (‘there’), etc.?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Re the off-topic question - The transliteration system I prefer for [Ancient] Greek is essentially the one the Romans used when borrowing Greek words. ει is usually ī except before vowels when it's ē, η is always ē, ου is ū, ω is ō.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet For my own purposes I have it divided by language, but I suppose the term should be usable to describe valid answers in any game where you are given the word "kan" and have to write the original.  (Ideally I use it in an example sentence for better disambiguation but I don't have a lot of example sentences entered yet.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good question. You are looking at something that is definitely a homograph, yet needs further qualification. There may be no single word for this- would homographic transliteration work?

@Barmar- what you are referring to is called a transcription (the rendering of the *sounds* of the original into symbols).

Comment: "Homographs in transliteration" would probably be the phrase I'd go to if I had to resort to one.

Comment: If the transliterator can use accented characters or macrons, and not just a-z, then the OP's example is not an especially good one: `basīlēa` versus `basilēa`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a term for this and it is due to the differences between writing systems and problematic nature of transliteration. For example, one English word may have several transliterations in Mandarin also; because the abundance of homophones in Chinese increases the number of similarly acceptable English-to-Chinese transliterations. Meanwhile, Chinese is a tonal language also and the tone of a character can help distinguish homophones; but it might not be possible in the transliterated version.

Another problem is that there can be different systems to transcribe Chinese characters to English. For example, older works often used *Wade-Giles* system but *pinyin* is becoming the standard in Western scholarship.

Here is a brief explanation why different Chinese characters can have the same transliteration:

> In Chinese, one written character represent one spoken syllable. Because there are over 50,000 of these characters represented by just over 400 spoken syllables, there can be hundreds of distinct characters sharing the same transliteration.<sup>41</sup>
>
> <sub><sup>41</sup> I'm describing here modern Chinese in the standard Mandarin dialect; these numbers vary over different dialects and historical periods.</sub>
>
> <sub>*"Imagined Civilizations: China, the West, and Their First Encounter"*
> By Roger Hart</sub>

Comment: "hundreds of distinct characters sharing the same transliteration" - I guess he didn't have a word for the concept either.

Comment: @Muskworker: Yes but the real answer is "there is no term". I offered further explanation also. Making up new terms is off topic here. I could make up too if I wanted, for example: *homotransliteration* or *homotransliterated words* but they sound off.